# api for nginx to ask when requests are finished?

Tags: nginx

I have a rolling restart script that right now sleeps after taking a node out of the pool of nginx.  It would be much preferable to query how many outstanding requests there are on the server we took out fo the pool so that when it goes down to zero, we can immediately stop the webserver, upgrade and restart it.

We basically have 5 steps

1. rollingRestartStep1 - removes node 1 from LB, sleeps, and then upgrades it
2. test directly on the node(make sure it started, etc)
3. rollingRestartStep2 - puts node 1 back in rotation of LB
4. test a bit on LB until it hits the new node, makes sure it's working
5. rollingRestartStep5 - this does step 1 and 3 over and over on all the other nodes
6. basic testing

Ideally, we REALLY want to stop sleeping because it is causing 30 minute rolling restart times right now that could easily be avoided.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing graceful shutdown with nginx then it serves all current requests before quit. http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html

Comment: yes, I am already aware of that, but I have to sleep in my script like it says in my question.  I need to ask nginx are those current requests finished every 5 seconds.  My first sentence was trying to get at that "I have a rolling restart script that right now sleeps after taking a node out of the pool of nginx"  ie. I remove the server line and reload already, but need to know exactly when nginx knows there are no more requests to that server.

Comment: oh, and I think this is very clear in my first step as well.... "removes node 1 from LB, sleeps, and then upgrades it"  (ie. we already do that)

Comment: Use `wait` instead of sleep: `man wait`. Or, if you need to know remotely, look at [the stub status module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpStubStatusModule).

Comment: wait on remote is exactly what I want, but NOT total nginx requests.  I need the number of requests for webserverA, webserverB, etc. etc. so when werbserverA is zero requests, I can immediately stop, upgrade with the script.  that module is total nginx requests which does not help.

Comment: I am gracefully shutting down WEBSERVERS...ie. a rolling restart, not nginx.  a module showing requests on webserver A would be awesome.  is there a module for that?

Comment: Probably no. I've never heard of such a module.